# Is there a way to run java code when executing "Maven Deploy"?

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I have been given the task of developing code that generates an email when a user deploys new code to our servers. I already have the code to generate the email. However Im trying to run this code when we add new code to our servers. We currently deploy new code to our servers using the MAVEN Deploy command in Eclipse. I was wondering if there is a way to run a java main method or something along those lines when a user selects Maven Deploy in Eclipse?

Comment: I think this should help you: http://www.vineetmanohar.com/2009/11/3-ways-to-run-java-main-from-maven/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure of your actual use case or if this is the best approach, but you can run java programs using the maven exec plugin. See here for more details: http://www.mojohaus.org/exec-maven-plugin/examples/example-exec-for-java-programs.html

Comment: that linked gave me exactly what I needed. Thank you very much Alexandru"